# Bayesian reparametrization are they equivalent?

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, parameterization, dirichlet-distribution

Suppose that we are in a Bayesian context, we we have the following matrix $n,$ $K\times K,$ as parameter, and we assume that

$$n_{ij}\sim Pois(w*w_{ij})$$

where $w\sim Gamma(N+1,1)$ and $w_{ij}$ is another parameter which follows a dirichlet distribution. Can the following be seen as a different parametrization for $n_{ij}$? Since the average of $w$ is $N+1$, and $\mathbb{E}[n_{ij}]=(N+1)w_{ij}$ then

$$n_{ij}\sim Mult(N+1,w_{ij})$$